# Kubernetes pod, allow HTTP access just from VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, nginx-ingress

Okay, maybe I'm not searching correctly since I didn't found the answer, so help me please.

So, I have an EKS cluster (kubernetes cluster provided by AWS), and I have some web applications running there.

These applications are exposed to the internet through one Network LoadBalancer from AWS and a NGINX ingress, like this:

> Client/browser -> Domain -> Network LoadBalancer -> Cluster -> Nginx ingress controller -> Application

And that works just fine, but **I want to create a new application in this cluster, and allow access only from a VPN.**

At first, **I thought** that I could **create a new Network load balancer, but internal**, and that maybe would work, however, **is that necessary?** **There is another way?** If there is not another way, could someone explain to me how to do that (if it works, because I'm not sure that works).

So, is that possible? How?

Comment: would [IP based whitelisting](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range) work for your use-case?

Comment: @mforsetti I will try that and see